# How to use optgroup twice inside select tag in a vuejs template in a laravel project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i have a laravel project. i am using vuejs on that project.i have used select tag on my project.and inside select tag i have used two optgroup tags.but inside vuejs template if i use two optgroup tags it only showing the first optgroup tag label.it's not showing the second optgroup tag label or the option tag output.

how should i do it or any alternative way to get the same result?

```
<select>

   <optgroup label="1st  labael">

         <optgroup label="2nd label">

                <option> some option </option>

          </optgroup>

     </optgroup>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**optgroup** has only one level in selects

That means you can insert it only like

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="1st  label">
        <option> some option </option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2st label">
        <option> some option </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

In alternative ways, you can use the custom select's packages like [Vue Select](https://vue-select.org/)

Comment: Can you please exactly show me how should I do it? I am not getting it.@Anatolii

Comment: I studied package more carefully and, unfortunately, it doesn't can work with optgroup yet. But I found [VueMaterial](https://vuematerial.io/components/select/).

I am not sure **this** package works as you want, but here is [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-material-groups-zgtex)

Comment: that worked fine. thank you. but i still don't understand what's wrong with the two optgroup in bootstrap

Comment: It's not bootstrap - it's just HTML rules :)

Comment: @grabtui it's not worked btw. it's not selecting a option. it's showing the option but not selecting